# Entity framework returns old value of an updated column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I use .NET so I have an endpoint which does an update on some columns and then it should construct a JSON object from 2 tables and return it, containing the updated column. Precisely, I have a diagram which has attributes in it. Each diagram can have multiple attributes (imagine it like a sql table with columns). The flow goes like this:

```
1. updateAttribute;
2. getDiagramIDs;
3. getDiagramDetails from DiagramIDs;
4. constructJSONObject from the diagramDetails and its attributes.
Example of return JSON:
{
   DiagramID: 1
   Attributes: [
   {
     AttributeID: 2
     Description: 'test'
   }
   ...
   ]
}
```

My class for the Diagram is:

```
[Table("Diagram", Schema = "core")]
public partial class Diagram: BaseEntity
{
    public Diagram()
    {
        Attribute = new HashSet<Attribute>();
    }
     public long ID{ get; set; }
     [InverseProperty("Entity")]
     public virtual ICollection<Attribute> Attribute { get; set; }
}
```

My class for the Attribute is:

```
[Table("Attribute", Schema = "core")]
public partial class Attribute : BaseEntity
{
    public long DiagramID { get; set; }
    public long? ID{ get; set; }
    public int ColumnOrder { get; set; }
}
```

In order to get both the Diagrams info and the Attributes info, I use

```
await _context.Diagram.Where(x => diagramIDs.Contains(x.ID)).Include(x => x.Attribute).ToListAsync();
```

where `diagramIDs` is a list of DiagramIDs I pass as a client. This returns me the older version of the Attributes i.e. returns me the Attributes like they were before the update. An example scenario:

```
1. I edit the description to 'test123';
2. Manually check in MSSQL, it is edited successfully;
3. await _context.Diagram.Where(x => diagramIDs.Contains(x.ID))
.Include(x => x.Attribute)
.ToListAsync(); - returns me 'test' instead of 'test123' even tho 'test123' is stored in the database 
and the update function was called far before this.
```

Do you have any ideas what could be the reason for this kind of behavior and if anyone ever experienced it, how can I solve it? Could it be an `await/async` problem, let's say concurrency?

Comment: Are you using the same `DbContext` instance across your application, and updating the column from outside of your application?

Comment: Yes, I use the same `DbContext`. What do you mean precisely by `outside of my application`? The request body, with the new `Description` comes from my client app yes, but then I do the update in `.NET`

Comment: I'm assuming this is ASP.NET? Reusing the same `DbContext` instance across the entire application is not supported, and will lead to errors. You should configure it as a "scoped" service, and have one instance per request.

Comment: The `DbContext` caches the records it reads (excluding non-tracking queries). If you read the record in instance `1`, update it in instance `2`, and then read it again in instance `1`, you will get the original values back, not the updated values. By making it a "scoped" service, you will use a new instance for each request, which will not have any cached values, and should return the updated value as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the brief description!